# CKEDITOR won't resize

Tags: css, ckeditor

I have a ckeditor that currently has a height and width of auto, but I would like to make these parameters fixed.  I first tried to set the rows and cols but this did not work:

```
<textarea id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="10" cols="10">
    Example text goes here
</textarea>
```

Then I tried to use the config file with this code (which still doesn't work):

```
<script>
    CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function(config) {
        config.height = '100px';
        config.width = '100px';
    };
</script>
```

After using both of these methods, the height and width of the ckeditor is still auto (checked with chrome's inspect element feature)

My example: http://strawberrycv.com/test.php

The code to this page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>


  <script src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>

  <style>
    #ckeWrapper{
        height: 700px;
        width: 600px;
    }

  </style>

</head>
<body>
<form>
<div id='ckeWrapper'>
        <textarea id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="60" cols="90">
            the text goes here
        </textarea>
</div>
        <script>
            // Replace the <textarea id="editor1"> with a CKEditor
            // instance, using default configuration.
            CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
        </script>



</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you create a sample page which proves that?

Comment: have you checked the CKEditor documentation: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_howtos_interface - you could wrap the editor in a <div> and put the height and width on that?

Comment: @97ldave  the div allows me to control the width but the height is still the same (also i edited my code)

Comment: @Reinmar i edited my original post

Answer (score -2):

hey i just started using this plugin but i think i got a clue for u:
find the api here: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config

And look for the corresponding JS line that should go in the bottom ''

After you have defined the texarea JS takes over, so I'd say you need to do your editing in the JS instead of the CSS.